# VSCode Debugger & Typescript: Step Over/Into goes to JS file

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm new to VSCode and I use it for debugging node.js(Typescript) code.
Something that I notices it that if my code stops in a breakpoint and then I use the option "Step Over" or "Step Into", the code goes to the post-compiled Javascript file, instead of the relevant Typescript file.

Do you know how to make the debugger go only to Typescript files as a result of using "Step into" / "Step over"?

My settings.json file look this way:

```
{
            "type": "node2",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch TS Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\app.ts",
            "preLaunchTask": "tsc: build - tsconfig.json",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}\\**\\*.js"
            ],
            "smartStep": true,
            "outputCapture": "std",
            "console": "internalConsole",
        },
```

Comment: did you find the solution for it?

Answer (score 3):

Try to set `smartStep` to `true` in your launch config file (`launch.json`).

You can find more information about this option in the documentation [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_smart-stepping).

> With the `smartStep` attribute set to `true` in a launch configuration, VS
>   Code will automatically skip 'uninteresting code' when stepping
>   through code in the debugger. 'Uninteresting code' is code that is
>   generated by a transpiling process but is not covered by a source map
>   so it does not map back to the original source.

Comment: 'smartStep' is already set to true, and unfortunately it doesn't help :-(

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I set the following option in my `tsconfig.json` and then deleted the directory specified by `outDir` in `tsconfig.json`.

```
{
  ...
 "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */
  ...
}
```

Then when the project was rebuilt on the next debug, the stepping operations seemed to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

***Updated***

maybe try to toggle the `Enable Source Mapped Stepping` in debugger

- `@command:extension.js-debug.enableSourceMapStepping` 
  `@command:extension.js-debug.disableSourceMapStepping`

[image]

[image]

---

<sub>***Old answer & may be wrong***

*(Might not be relevant, but this worked for me, idk why)*

Maybe you can try to open this single project (/ folder) in a **new workspace** -- with no other projects / folders, just this **single** one.

And then run the code.

- My situation is bit diff -- once I ran the code, the debugger directly jumps to the compiled ts file (yes, a ts file not js, idk why).

  - (I am using `tsx` to run the ts code.)
- I guess this may due to vscode has some config that tries to search from **the default root project dir** -- but unable to correctly locate it if you have multi projects in your workspace.
- *(feels everything was fine for me before, till now.)*</sub>